# Sharing Python file with non-standard modules?

Tags: python, module, package

Long time reader, first time OP.

I've written a program using 'Beautiful Soup' from the 'bs4' library and the 'requests' library (which is the most amazing thing, achieved in less than five minutes what I had failed to do in a week with urllib2), both of which I had to install (I'm using PyCharm CE).

If I'm sharing this file, what's the best way to make sure these modules are folded in with the package if I send it to someone? Or post it somewhere?

I'm running Python 3.5.2 in PyCharm CE

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably asking about [packaging and distributing python projects](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/). That document describes how to package your project and upload it to PyPI.

If you only want to share a snippet of code, tell those who you are sending it to to install dependencies first via `pip`. Share the needed `pip install <package>` commands list.